# Java - Problems with understanding inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am facing some problems about inheritance in Java.
I can't understand why the following two programs have those outputs! 
Could anyone help me? :)

1)

```
public class A {
    int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    int foo() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    int bar(A a) {
        return a.foo();
    }
}

C x = new C();  
System.out.println(x.bar(x));

// OUTPUT:2
```

2)

```
public class A {
    int e=1;
}

public class B extends A {
    int e=2;
}

public class C extends B {
    int bar(A a){
        return a.e;
    }
}

C x= new C();
System.out.println(x.bar(x));

// OUTPUT:1
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you're passing in an object of type `C` into the print function. The `bar` function asks for an object of type `A`, but it's still acceptable for you to pass in an object of type `C` since it is a subclass of `A`. So first of all, it's important to keep in mind that `a.foo()` and `a.e` are being called on a `C` object.

So what is happening in both cases is that it's searching for the lowest attribute or method in the list. Here is a very simplified version of what Java is doing in part 1:

1. Hey, you've passed in an object of type `C` to the `bar` method! Now let's call its `foo` method.
2. Whoops! `C` doesn't have a `foo` method! Let's take the next step up to the `B` class to see if it has a `foo` method.
3. Yay! `B` has a `foo` method, so let's call it. No need to work our way up to the `A` class because we've already found what we need in B.

It's all about understanding that the parameter was downcast from `A` to `C`. The exact same sort of logic is used in part 2. It notices that an object of type `C` was passed in, so it gets the `e` attribute from object `B` since its the lowest class in the hierarchy that contains that attribute.

Hopefully that answers your question!

Comment: You wrong about example 2 - there output is "1". The class B has its own member e, which is hidden for outside. If B wouldn't have the member e but set a value to it, we'd get an output "2", but it's not so we read a member's value of class A

Comment: Hm, with your logic the answer in the second program would be 2, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Johanna Is question for me?

Comment: No, the question is for Jake Fairbaim, but if you can explain it to me better, I don't have a problem :p

Comment: @Johanna I already did. Jake Fairbairn is right about example 1 - there's virtual method works, but in second one a member e from B doesn't overrides member from A. Class it's like a structrure: {members; [table of virtual funcions]}. When an app is executed, and you call a method, JVM looks for it in a table and calls function of a real object, but it can't resolve something like that for a member, so it just gives you e of A.

Comment: Ok guys, I got it! Thank you very much!! :) :)